# Multiple regression when the dependant variable is unmeasured or hidden

Tags: regression, estimation, regression-coefficients

Say I was measuring the individual performance of each of a group of athletes every week. I measure things like running speed, jumping height, grip strength etc.

I want to use these scores with multiple regression, or some other method, to measure fitness. But I cannot measure fitness directly.

Could I estimate the regression weights by choosing those that give the lowest coefficient of variation of the dependant variable, or is there another method(s)?

The fitness measure will vary from individual to individual, and will change over time for each individual.

I could convert these raw scores into z-scores if that would help.

Comment: The ultimate issue, and the very first one to address, is what you might mean by "fitness" when you have no direct measurement of it.  It is essential that you provide some clear, quantitative definition along with some model of how it might be related to what you do measure, for otherwise everything you are doing is subjective and undefined: your sense of "fitness" might be entirely different from someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

Regression is the wrong tool here. Regression demands a known dependent variable.

What you are trying to do is estimate a latent variable -- one that cannot be directly measured -- and the right tool is probably factor analysis, at least to start with and at least as part of the procedure.

Comment: Fair enough: but suppose one or more such latent variables are constructed.  What might justify characterizing any of them as "fitness"?  What tests or procedures could one apply to support such a conclusion?